# Ultrasonic Sensors and Raspberry pi 4

Tags: pi-4

I was making a robot with a raspberry pi 4 which will have four ultrasonic sensors on all its four sides..

I was looking up in google to see the schematic of the connections and noticed that there are 2 resistors connected to the echo pin.

[image: Schematic]

Image Source: https://tutorials-raspberrypi.com/

**Note that the image has a raspberry pi 3 but I am working with a raspberry pi 4**

I do understand that the resistor is kept to limit the current, but my first question is that will it work without the resistor and is it a **must** for the resistor? The ultrasonic sensor works fine with the 5V output pin from an Arduino without any resistors, so it should work fine with the 5V of my raspberry pi 4 also right?

Now to my second question..

I want to connect 4 ultrasonic sensors to my rpi4, so should I connect the resistors to all the echo pins of the ultrasonic sensors?

Comment: The two resistors are a voltage divider. The echo pin is 5V. The GPIO can only run at 3.3V. You need that on EVERY echo pin or you will destroy your Raspberry Pi with over voltage on the GPIOs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **2 resistors** form a voltage divider to reduce the 5V output of the sensor to a value which is safe for the Pi GPIO which is a 3.3V device.

**EACH** sensor NEEDS its own voltage divider!
NOTE The values are not critical, in fact I would use equal value resistors to produce 2.5V output which is safely above the GPIO threshold.

You might find https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html?highlight=distance%20sensor#distance-sensor easier to implement.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I do understand it reduces the voltage but my ultrasonic sensors works fine with the 5V ouput pin of an Arduino with no resistors.. why is that the rpi needs resistors?

Comment: This has NOTHING to do with OUTPUT - the INPUT to the Pi MUST NOT exceed 3.3V

Comment: oh.. I understand now.. but what if I use the 3.3V pin for powering the ultrasonic sensors, will the sensors work fine or not?

Comment: And also @milliways can you help me out in this.. can you just confirm that the tutorial in this website is correct? would mean a lot! Link to website: https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-range-sensor-on-the-raspberry-pi

Comment: @404-BrainNotFound The basic mathematics seems OK, but I can't confirm anything I haven't tried. I have already posted the link I would use. I definitely wouldn't use sudo.

Comment: These sensors typically will not operate properly from 3V3, they need 5V power.  When I tried powering from 3V3 I got random results for the range.

Comment: @Milliways as per the page you linked, should I use a 470 ohm resistor and a 220 ohm resistor **(the 1st and 2nd band of the resistor also looks like orange, so is it a 330 ohm resistor)**?

Comment: I think I got it @Milliways, it is a 330 ohm resistor and a 470 ohm resistor right?